# How do you get the routeParam element for the current route?

Tags: parameters, routes, react-router, param, routeparams

I'm using react-router 2.7.0.  In my route configuration there are nested routes each with their own parameter of the same name.  E.g.  /route1/:entityId which has a nested route of /route2/:entityId.  The params and routeParams props supplied by react-router supply these values to both content components as an array.  I.e. the path /route1/43/route2/56 will give the array [43,56] as the value for the entityId param.

This seems counter intuitive, I'd expect the routeParams provided to route1's component would be 43 and route2's to be 56, but instead I get the array of two elements to both components.

How do I determine which element in the array is for each component?
Note: I cannot just use the index as my routing is built up from metadata, so there might be other routes nested in between route1 and route2 and each route is unaware of the other routes it's nested inside of.  So there could potentially be 5 routes in play and route1 and route2 could be at any index 0-4

Comment: Hmm you should be able to access the `params` prop which is not an array but an object with keys matching your variable route names `props.params.entityId`

Comment: props.params.entityId returns [43,56]

Comment: Are you forced to use the same variable name `entityId` for both parts of your route? Can you change it to `/route1/:entityId1/:route2:entityId2` ?

Comment: Unfourtunately yes.  I cannot do that due to the nature of the routes not knowing about each other.

Comment: You say the routes are built up dynamically--meaning at some point you're looping through some data and generating the path property... can you add the index during this construction to the variable name?

Comment: Yes that is my last resort: Add unique suffix to each param name and then use that suffix to access each parameter